# Authorization verification in middle ware razor output

Tags: authentication, razor

I'm at a loss how to prevent a middle ware page output.

My Startup.cs Configuration includes:

```
   services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
           .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
           .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new[] { "User.Read", "Mail.Read", "User.ReadBasic.All", "https://management.azure.com/user_impersonation" })
           .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("Graph"))
           .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

and a specific document.razor page has the following attribute set:

```
@attribute [Authorize(Roles = "User, Admin, Finance")]
```

and all is well, nobody can see the page unless authorized for it. However, there are child items on the page that when clicked, will send a pdf via a middle ware pipeline, since the pdf can be very large, in this way:

```
    public void ReportRowClickHandler(GridRowClickEventArgs arg)
    {
        VerifiedRequisiteModel requisite = (VerifiedRequisiteModel)arg.Item;
        int reportnumber = requisite.VerifyingReport;
        if (reportnumber != 0)
        {
            IReportData rdb = new ReportData();
            try
            {
                ReportModel report = rdb.GetWithReport(reportnumber);
                NavigateToNewTab("/ShowPdf.mdwr?reportid=" + report.Report);
            }
            catch (Exception) { toastService.ShowError($"Report not found, perhaps deleted?"); }
        }
    }
```

and the middle ware output is done this way (thanks to someone here at stackoverflow!):

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public class ShowPdf
    {
        private IReportData pdfdb;
        private ReportModel myReport;

        public ShowPdf(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            //_next = next; no call to _next.Invoke(context) because the handler is at the end of the request pipeline, so there will be no next middleware to invoke.
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            this.pdfdb = new ReportData();
            myReport = pdfdb.GetWithReport(Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.Query["reportid"]));
            byte[] reportBytes = myReport.ReportDocument;
            context.Response.ContentType = myReport.DocumentType;

            context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition",
                                "attachment; " +
                                "filename=\"iTraxReportDoc." + myReport.DocumentType +"\"; " +
                                "size=" + reportBytes.Length + "; " +
                                "creation-date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("R").Replace(",", "") + "; " +
                                "modification-date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("R").Replace(",", "") + "; " +
                                "read-date=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("R").Replace(",", ""));
            await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(reportBytes);
        }
    }

    public static class ShowPdfExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseShowPdf(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<ShowPdf>();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this page is not protected and when someone types https://someunsecurewebsite.com/ShowPdf.mdwr?reportid=xxx, then they will get the report without being authorized.

I'm not sure how to do this. I have tried to convert the ShowPDF.cs into a full blown razor page but then it's not recognized because of the mapping in Startup.cs

Turning the ShowPDF.cs class into a ShowPDF.razor page will result of an error in the Startup.cs at the line

```
appBranch > {
   appBranch.UseShowPdf();
}
```

stating that "IApplicationBuilder does not contain a definition for UseShowPDF and no accessible extension method 'UseShowPdf' is accepting a first argument of type "IApplicationBuilder".

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

After finally diving into the ASP.NET Core Middleware document, I started to understand the overall flow.
[image: Middleware Flow Order]

The solution was in the correct ordering of the calls in Startup.cs in the Configure() method:

```
 app.UseHttpsRedirection();
 app.UseStaticFiles();
 app.UseRouting();
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
 app.MapWhen(
            context => context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("ShowPdf.mdwr", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase),
            appBranch => {
                appBranch.UseShowPdf();
            });
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
      endpoints.MapControllers();
      endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
      endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
      endpoints.MapRazorPages();
   });
```

So, originally I had the call to MapWhen before the calls to UseAuthentication() and UseAuthorization()